# Using pg_dump, export entire schema for all tables and data for one table

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'd like to export the entire schema using pg_dump as well as the data within a single table. I know I can do something like this:

`pg_dump -s mydatabase > db.sql; pg_dump -a -t some_table mydatabase >> db.sql`

However, it's somewhat inelegant, and the output of the second half repeats a lot of settings and comments that the first half already provides such as:

```
-- Dumped from database version 9.6.8
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.8

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using both is restricted

```
t=# \! pg_dump -d t -h localhost -p 5400 -s -a -t so12
pg_dump: options -s/--schema-only and -a/--data-only cannot be used together
```

so obviously - no. you have to do them sequentially...

`SET SESSION` statements just set the session "parameters" - they won't duplicated data or such - why you want to avoid them?..

I can't imagine any faster commands executed, e./g. compared to `select now()`:

```
t=# \timing on
Timing is on.
t=# SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET
Time: 0.312 ms
t=# select now();
             now
------------------------------
 2018-04-01 17:40:37.52727+01
(1 row)

Time: 17.182 ms
```

Comment: I don't have a great reason for avoiding the extra `SET SESSION` statements. I just wanted to make the file a little cleaner and more straightforward.